# Datatable undefined type - Angular11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular11, ngx-datatable

We have services.ts . Which needs 2 arguments

**UPDATED**
seems like i was looking the error wrong. this method was causing the console error

```
private checkLink(row, options) {
        if (options.type ==='link' || options.type ==='custom-method') {
            if (options.type === 'link' || (options.type === 'custom-method' && (row.user_id === this.userData.id) || this.authService.permission('view_subject_data') || this.userData.id === row.section.user_id || this.userData.id === 1)) {
                if (options.permission) {
                    if (this.authService.permission(options.permission)) {
                        this.router.navigate([`${options.link}/${row[options.linkKey]}`]);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate([`${options.link}/${row[options.linkKey]}`]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Im calling it to my html table which is used by many components.

```
<span [innerHtml]="datatableService.setColumnData(row[column.prop], column.options, row)"
```

Here's the data that im passing to `setColumnData`

```
columns = [
        {
            name: 'User',
            prop: 'last_name',
            options: {
                type: 'piped',
                pipes: ['displayFullName']
            },
        },
        { 
            name: 'Action',
            prop: 'description'
        },
        {
            name: 'Time',
            prop: 'created_at',
            options: {
                type: 'piped',
                pipes: ['formatDateTime']
            },
        },

    ];
```

Which gives me `type undefined` but code works. I just need to get rid of console.log error.

[image]

I know i just need to supply the needed arguments like this. And it works no errors.

```
{
    name: 'Action',
    prop: 'description',
    options: ''
},
```

But the problem is i need to change all the similar `columns` variable all across the project. Is there anyway easier or clean way to do this?

Comment: One cannot just *disable undefined*. Type your objects, then the compiler will force you in the right direction. As a bonus, you won't get this kind of runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes bro. But when i add ```options``` to my ```columns``` array. The error doesn't show. Like in the last part in my post.

Comment: I understand that, but to get rid of the error in all of the places, you need to do your if check everywhere. How come you did not get this error until now? You said you have this in a lot of places.

Comment: Im not the one who code this. Maybe my past senior devs. Im just fixing the code now cause most of them left. I see thanks for the hint bro.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the service & storing the value in your component.ts file through ngAfterViewInit instead of calling it directly in the component.html file, The values are initiated after the view is rendered so it should throw undefined, since the value is not initiated

```
public tableData:yourType = []

ngAfterViewInit():void{
  this.tableData = this.datatableService.setColumnData(this.row[this.column.prop], this.column.options, this.row)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro. Not yet bro. thinking of, if check like octavian suggested

Comment: okay bro i would recommend using the ts file for handling all the data coming from a service, since we don't have much control over the data in the html file :)